# This request has no response data avialble in python/ajax

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, http

I make the web app based on python for back-end and jquery(ajax) to send requests for the back. Response formed and sent but the network logs in chrome say that this request has not response data. My background and page are running on the localhost.
How to fix that error?

Here is my query in AJAX

```html
  <body>
        <button onclick="enter()">
            
        </button>
           </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function enter(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:JSON.stringify({"cmd":"register","player":{"login":"login","pass":"","temp":1}})
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(typeof(data));
                })
                
            
}
    </script>
```

Here is my Python code which responses to the query.

```
import socket
import sqlite3
import json
import os
import random
import string

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('',8080))
while True:
    sock.listen(1)
    connection, address = sock.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(1024)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        answer = ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
         + "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\n"
         + "Content-Type: json\n"
         +json.dumps({"a":"b"})).encode('utf-8')
        print(answer)
        connection.send(answer)


connection.close()

conn.close()
```

[image: responce of server]

Timing for the request is about one minute and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **success(result,status,xhr)** parameter in ajax instead of **.done()**

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
 type: 'POST',
 dataType: 'json',
 data:JSON.stringify({"cmd":"register","player":{"login":"login","pass":"","temp":1}}),
 success: function (data,status,xhr) {
   console.log(data);
   console.log(typeof(data));
 }
})
```

Comment: The result is the same. And I don't know why waiting for results is about 40 secs.